# Toggle little / big endian in unpack() in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

In Ruby 1.9.3, you can do

```
    "\x00\x01".unpack 'S' #=> 1 * 256 + 0 = 256, my machine use little endian by default
    "\x00\x01".unpack 'S>' #=> 0 * 256 + 1 = 1
```

But Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't have the ">" "<" annotation. So in 1.8.7, what is the best way to do unpack with big endian?

Comment: Have you got your examples mixed up? You’ve swapped the `x00` and `x01` bytes _and_ the format in the second example, they both equal 1.

Comment: You are right, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "\x00\x01"
puts str.unpack 'S'

p str.reverse
puts str.reverse.unpack 'S'


--output:--
256
"\001\000"
1
```

Comment: You should really add some explaination.

Comment: My bad. I was also considering this method. The only down side here is that requires knowledge of the endianness of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `n` for network (big) endian 2 byte values (`N` for 4 byte ints) and `v` for little endian 2 byte integers (`V` for 4 bytes). See [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-unpack).

```
"\x00\x01".unpack 'n'
# => [1] 
"\x00\x01".unpack 'v'
# => [256]
```

You really should look into upgrading your Ruby version if possible.

Comment: Thanks. I should've pointed out - is there such a way to do it for signed integers?